# pass variable to function: var image = dymo.label.framework.loadImageAsPngBase64(variable);

Tags: javascript, dymo

How can I pass a filename variable into the following line?

```
var image = dymo.label.framework.loadImageAsPngBase64("http://www.example.com/label.png");
```

The following obviously doesn't work, tried single quotes and several different variations but none of it worked.

```
var file_name = "label.png";
var image = dymo.label.framework.loadImageAsPngBase64("http://www.example.com/" + file_name + ");
```

Comment: Does `loadImageAsPngBase64("http://www.example.com/" + file_name);` not work? (Without the last plus sign)

Comment: What's the last `"`?  The one after `file_name + ` and before `);`

Comment: The last + should not be there. I had tried without it as well. The problem was actually that in the script file_name was an object. I added ".value"  and it worked. Thank you both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved: issue was with the variable in the script. It was an object so I had to add .value to obtain to obtain the value.